# People Search Query - Need to Filter Out External/Groups

Tags: people-search

I have this general people query running:

```
{SearchBoxQuery} ContentClass=urn:contentclass=spspeople
```

I'm getting everything though. External users and groups, including meeting rooms.
I'm new to queries and learning but can't figure this one out.

How do I exclude external users and groups in my query?

Comment: How do you define an external user? Is this on-prem or online? And there is no one way to do this. Or do you have a field/domain which is present on all internal users?

Answer (score 1):

If you want only external users and groups, you can use Site Users webpart from Social Collaboration category. It will list out groups and users which exist in SharePoint site.